# How can I get the source configuration via jinja in dbt models?

Tags: sql, jinja2, dbt

have several source.yml configuration files which indicates the key-value for each table. We have one source.yml file for each customer and the tables set for each customer would be different; then, the models would be different for each customers e.g. I have the following source.yml file for a customer:

```
- name: channels
  tables:
     name: table1
     identifier: identifier1
```

I need a jinja function call to verify that the table1 is existed in the `source.yml` file or not. I tried and searched a lot: First, I tried `source(“channels”,“table1”)` but it gives me the error when the table is not existed e.g. source(“channels”,“table1”). Second, I verified the `config()` function call but it doesn’t have any information around the source.yml.

In a word, I need a function such as `config.has_key('sources.channels.table3')` to verify that table1 is existed and table2 is not existed. Would you please give me any hints to check the configurations is existed in the yml files or not?

Comment: To clarify...are you asking for something that checks if the table is defined in the yml file or if the table exists in the database?

Comment: I'm checking the table is defined in the yml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm finding a solution in the following [link](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/how-can-i-get-the-source-configuration-via-jinja/7616/5).

In summary, we can make a macro in dbt such as below to verify the table is existed in the source.yml configuration or not.

```
{% macro check_source(source_name, table_name) %}

{%- if execute -%}
    {% for source in graph.sources.values() %}
        {%- if source.source_name == source_name and source.name == table_name -%}

            {{ return(true) }}

        {%- endif -%}
    {%- endfor -%}

    {{ return(false) }}

{%- endif -%}

{% endmacro %}
```